# Could not cast value of type 'nsnull' to 'nsstring'

Tags: ios, firebase

I'm trying to retrieve images from firebase when I start the simulated it crash and I get this message " **Could not cast value of type 'NSNull' (0x10eaf2378) to 'NSString' (0x10eee2b20).** "
this is my code

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var gameName: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var videoImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var uploadImage: UIButton!


var ref = Firebase(url:"https://xxx.firebaseio.com/images/")
var imageRef = Firebase(url:"https://xxx.firebaseio.com/images/image/string")
var base64String: NSString!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    imageRef.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) -> Void in

        self.base64String = snapshot.value as? String
        let decodeData = NSData(base64EncodedString: snapshot.value as! String, options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions())
        let decodeImage = UIImage(data: decodeData!)
        self.videoImage.image = decodeImage
        print(self.base64String)
        }) { (error) -> Void in
            print(error.description)
    }

}
```

Comment: it looks like snapshot.value is coming back empty. put a check in there to see.

Answer (score 0):

```
imageRef.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) -> Void in

        guard let unwrappedSnapShot = snapshot.value as? String ,
              let decodeData        = NSData(base64EncodedString: unwrappedSnapShot, options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions())
              else {  /*handle snapshot or decodData was nil*/ return }

         let decodeImage = UIImage(data: decodeData)
         self.videoImage.image = decodeImage
         print(base64String)      
}) { (error) -> Void in
        print(error.description)
}
```

removed the use of IUO's you should not use those also
you should prob put a capture list in there to avoid retain cycles too

Comment: do I need to but some code in here ?! else {  /*handle snapshot or decodData was nil*/ return }

Comment: only if you want to put some code in there to help your self debug or if other parts of your code need to be handled from this failing

Comment: I tried the code but it didn't worked it didn't crash but the image didn't load on the UIImageView ?! do you think its the image the problem or the code I use to upload the image?1

Comment: yes you should put a break point and see what was nil unwrappedSnapShot or  decodeData. If it was Snapshot then no image, if it was decodedData the data was corrupt or bad